# Как пропустить строки по условию - не является class 'int'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, анализ-данных

```
import pandas as pd

price_from = 15000
price_to = 20000
qry = "@price_from <= `цена` <= @price_to and 'есть доставка' in `доставка`"


(pd
 .read_csv('data_file.csv', sep=';')
 .query(qry).sort_values('цена', ascending=False)
 .to_csv('new-data.csv', sep=';', index=False))
```

Как пропустить перед обработкой строки, в которых ячейка в колонке `цена` не является `class 'int'`, чтобы корректно обработался и сохранился файл?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону параметра `converters`   метода `read_csv`.  Полученные  NaN можно дропнуть как до сортировки, так и после. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40011531/in-pandas-when-using-read-csv-how-to-assign-a-nan-to-a-value-thats-not-the

Comment: Если задача разовая, можно просто в баше grep
`grep -e  " class 'int' " sourcefile > destinationfile` только строчки c паттерном.
`grep -vwE "(cat|rat)" sourcefile > destinationfile`и наоборот только строки без паттерна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', sep=';')
df['цена'] = pd.to_numeric(df['цена'], errors= 'coerce')

df = df.dropna(subset=['цена'])
df['цена'] = df['цена'].astype(int)

(df
 .query(qry)
 .sort_values('цена', ascending=False)
 .to_csv('new-data.csv', sep=';', index=False))
```

Comment: А в этой конструкции проверка .query(qry) идёт после проверки на numeric? Если из .query(qry) убрать часть условия "@price_from <= `цена` <= @price_to" и оставить только "'есть доставка' in `доставка" то скрипт отрабатывает корректно, если не убирать, то ошибка та же: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: @Jimmy, исправил ответ

Comment: спасибо, теперь всё работает, только цена стала float, добавился .0 к цифре.

Comment: @Jimmy, дык я вроде показал - [последняя правка ответа 4 мин. назад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1130547/revisions)...

Comment: не увидел что ответ обновился, спасибо!